# Open PDF as a web page

Tags: pdf, office-web-apps

I would like to know if there is a way to transform a PDF document in a web page, similar to what Office Web Apps do for Office documents.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After a quick google, found this, might be of some help: http://www.softwaregeek.com/download/pdfapps_convert_pdf_to_html.html

*Previous post, disregard but I do point out some slightly related other tools out there:*

*I know Bamboo do something along these lines here:
http://store.bamboosolutions.com/ps-16-5-office-to-pdf-conversion-business-component.aspx*

*The guys at Muhimbi also do some PDF stuff, but I think they only convert to PDF (could be wrong though, have a look: http://www.muhimbi.com) - a user on here is from Muhimbi so can give more advice if they do do such a product.*

Comment: The current version supports output of conversions in PDF and XPS format. A next version will support output in common image formats as well, e.g. TIFF, PNG, GIF, JPG. For details see http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The new office web apps are capable of that: http://melcher.it/2013/05/install-office-web-apps-2013-for-sharepoint-2013-with-pdf-preview/

Answer (score 0):

Go to Web application settings and change the settings of Browser file handling category

[image]
<sub>(source: [shareesblog.com](http://www.shareesblog.com/wp-content/uploads/BrowserFileHandling.jpg))</sub>

Finally go to Library  advance settings and Choose File open in the Browser option.

2) Another one is using page viewer web part you can achieve the PDF open in browser.

Answer (score -1):

I know a very good solution,the site link:[allowing PDFs to Open in a Browser in SharePoint 2010, the Right Way](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/brandon-atkinson/allowing-pdfs-open-browser-sharepoint-2010-the-right-way).Maybe helpful to you!